# Python: how to divide particles into different clusters according to their coordinates?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

Firstly, I generate 20 pairs of random numbers and use them as 2D spatial positions of 20 particles.

```
import numpy as np

positions = np.random.rand(20,2)
```

`Positions` is shown as follows

```
array([[0.96124789, 0.52413156],
   [0.5186589 , 0.4300743 ],
   [0.63357087, 0.70130091],
   [0.8213765 , 0.29515393],
   [0.68616945, 0.02020544],
   [0.71924115, 0.71630689],
   [0.92340942, 0.56007463],
   [0.17322848, 0.2455891 ],
   [0.3993029 , 0.53287478],
   [0.15887798, 0.60968053],
   [0.45877831, 0.88163765],
   [0.04565275, 0.76557075],
   [0.73800541, 0.71257644],
   [0.02784201, 0.10035848],
   [0.83830731, 0.66442518],
   [0.95518272, 0.37313694],
   [0.14761192, 0.8255784 ],
   [0.83576694, 0.18367566],
   [0.79187776, 0.52189936],
   [0.97585451, 0.97077229]])
```

What I want to do is classifying these particles into different clusters according to their spatial distribution. For this purpose, I build one K-d tree by importing `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` and find all pairs of points in this tree whose distance is at most 0.2 by using method `query_pairs`.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as kdtree

tree=kdtree(positions)
pairs= tree.query_pairs(r=0.2, output_type="ndarray")
pairs[np.argsort(pairs[:,0])]   # Sorting pairs along axis=0
```

The output of the code snippet above is shown as follows.

```
array([[ 0,  6],
       [ 0, 15],
       [ 0, 18],
       [ 0, 14],
       [ 1,  8],
       [ 2,  5],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 3, 17],
       [ 3, 15],
       [ 5, 12],
       [ 5, 14],
       [ 6, 18],
       [ 6, 14],
       [ 6, 15],
       [ 9, 11],
       [11, 16],
       [12, 18],
       [12, 14],
       [14, 18]], dtype=int64)
```

According to `pairs`, We can classify these particles into 3 clusters visually, i.e.

a). (0, 3, 5, 6, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18)

b). (1,8)

c). (9, 11, 16)

**So my question is that how to do this classification by Python itself?**

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? Before reinventing the wheel, there might be a way to accommodate your need in scipy stats.

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 Thanks for your comment, however, I didn't find any functionality of scipy stats to accommodate my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`KMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) from `sklearn`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

positions = np.array([[0.96124789, 0.52413156], [0.5186589, 0.4300743], [0.63357087, 0.70130091], [0.8213765, 0.29515393], [0.68616945, 0.02020544], [0.71924115, 0.71630689], [0.92340942, 0.56007463], [0.17322848, 0.2455891], [0.3993029, 0.53287478], [0.15887798, 0.60968053], [0.45877831, 0.88163765], [0.04565275, 0.76557075], [0.73800541, 0.71257644], [0.02784201, 0.10035848], [0.83830731, 0.66442518], [0.95518272, 0.37313694], [0.14761192, 0.8255784], [0.83576694, 0.18367566], [0.79187776, 0.52189936], [0.97585451, 0.97077229]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(positions)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (color, center) in enumerate(zip(['crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'limegreen'], kmeans.cluster_centers_)):
    ax.scatter(*positions[kmeans.labels_ == i].T, color=color, label=f'Cluster {i}')
    ax.scatter(*center, ec=color, fc='None', s=100)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

rnd = np.random.rand(10000, 2)
rnd_labels = kmeans.predict(rnd)
for i, (color) in enumerate(['crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'limegreen']):
    ax.scatter(*rnd[rnd_labels == i].T, ec='none', fc=color, marker='.', s=3)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0.95), loc='upper left')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: In fact, we don't know how many clusters before performing the program. And what we have are only coordinates of particles.

Comment: Well, you can run the code with different values of `k` and check `kmeans.inertia_`  (*"Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center"*) to stop  at a `k` that satisfies your needs. In general, there is no magic way to know which `k` is the most optimal for your application. (The default for `KMeans` is 8 clusters, but that number is completely arbitrarily.) See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set